# What is meant by Ordinary Time in Catholic Liturgy?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy

5th November is the 31st Sunday in Ordinary Time in the Liturgical Calendar of Roman Catholic Latin Rite . Some Oriental Rites eg. Syro Malabar Rite divide the Calendar into ' seasons' and do not serially number the Sundays.So,  what is meant by Ordinary Time ? Is there any other system of numbering  of Sundays in the Catholic Liturgical Calendar ?